# Norton always blocking my Firefox

Tags: firefox, norton-internet-security, norton-antivirus

I use Norton Internet Security and while browsing with Firefox in some sites I get message dialog from Norton say Firefox is attempting to listen for connections from other computers !! and page does not load until I allow that in Norton (I press ok)

[image]

Please advise how to allow Firefox to always work without this message from Norton.

BTW this does not happen with Chrome 
This happen for certain sites only.

Comment: Disable the functionality within Firefox and/or Norton.  Likely labeled as "Norton Safe Browsing" or something like that.  You can also just create an exception for Firefox itself.  Does this only happen after Firefox is updated is based on the website you visit?  Update your question, do not submit information, as a comment,

Comment: your solution seems working thanks. it is called safe surfing in Norton.

Comment: No it happen again in UPS site when I enter my email to get tracking info !!

Comment: If Firefox is attempting to use port 10146 then it's likely because of an extension or worst malicious javascript (i.e. crytpo mining).  Dubious websites have active campaigns to do that currently

Comment: Your Firefox may have been compromised (trojan), or an extension or other malware used on it.  I suggest backing up your Firefox bookmarks and any other settings, completely uninstalling Firefox, and installing firefox from a fresh-downloaded installer from the Mozilla site.

Comment: seems like an installed extension I will try disable one by one.